# Installation Cannot be performed fix this issue before installing. Virtualization is not enabled in BIOS Please enable before installing?

Tags: xilinx, xilinx-ise, xilinx-edk

I had already enabled Virualization from "BIOS". But still I am  unable to install please help??

> Is there is any alternate other then Xilinx.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling virtualization-based security, It worked for me.

- Open the Windows Security app.
- Click on "Device security" in the left pane.
- Under "Core isolation," click on "Core isolation details."
- Turn off "Memory integrity" and "Virtualization-based security."